# Clipping with a "buffer" around text in Postscript

Tags: postscript, clipping

(This is approaching [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326474/controlling-bitmap-density-when-printing-to-postscript-printer) from another angle.)

I am drawing maps. These can be seen as having three layers: At the bottom, there are solid colours representing things like forest and water, and low-contrast linework for things like “halos” on roads indicating classification. Then there is high-contrast linework, such as black lines representing road centrelines and black dotted lines representing paths. Finally, there are labels, usually black.

I would like the black lines to have gaps around the text, where the colours and lines of the bottom layer shines through.

In SVG, this can be done by setting a mask on the lines and drawing the text with a very wide stroke (to create the gap) into this mask.

Is there a way of expressing this in Postscript, short of writing my own font renderer to render “buffered” text as bézier paths? I can create a clip mask that goes right up to the edge of the text by drawing a rectangle around the page, charpath:ing the text and then doing eoclip, but how do I get the buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostScrtipt doesn't have any concept of transparency (modulo certain special cases like overprinting, imagemasks and chroma keyed images). There is also no standard way for a PostScript program to affect anything which has already been rendered, other than by drawing over it.

You can't 'get the buffer' if by that you mean get the pixels back from the page buffer in order to do your own compositing.

The only way I can see to do what you appear to want is to draw the black lines with the gaps already in place. Obviously this means moving the intelligence out of PostScript and putting it into your own application, you need to know, when you draw the black lines, where the text is going to be so that you can leave gaps in the lines in appropriate places.

Comment: By "get the buffer", I meant "How do I create the gap ('buffer zone') around the text". But that does not really affect your answer; I must "render" the text myself, either to create a clip path from it, or to clip the lines myself. :-(

Comment: You could pre-process the text, if you know what it is and where it is going before you draw the black lines. Its easy enough using charpath and pathbbox to find the rectangular area bounding a section of text (assuming you are using a simple show and not something more complex). You can then assemble a clipping path by appending each of those rectangles. Then draw the lines, then place the real text. But yes, since PostScript has an opaque imaging model, you have to do this yourself. You could use PDF instead, which has a transparent imaging model.

Comment: Yes, clipping to rectangles should be fairly straightforward, but I would like to get the effect of the brown road that passes through the "u" in "Sollentuna" in this map: https://kso.etjanster.lantmateriet.se/?e=666225&n=6591705&z=10&profile=default_terrangkartan_noauth . Maybe I'll have to look at PDF instead...

Comment: Ugly hack: 1. Draw background; 2. Draw lines; 3. (text) false charpath 4 setlinewidth strokepath clip ; 5. Draw background again (overpainting the bits of line that are supposed to be invisible); 6. Draw text.

Comment: Well you don't have to use rectangles, you could simply use charpath, but that will result in a **very** complex clip path, which will be extremely slow to process. As Ture implies above you probably want charpath and strokepath anyway (with a wide line width) and then use that as the clip path.